# Pycharm does not recognize logging.basicConfig handlers argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, pycharm

I have a `python` application that uses the python `logging` library for some time now for printing messages both on the screen and on time rotating files and works fine.

The logging configuration is as follows:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO if debug is not True else logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    handlers=[
                        TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_filename, when='midnight', interval=1),
                        logging.StreamHandler()
                    ]
                    )
```

My problem is that PyCharm keeps highlighting the `logging.basicConfig` part of the configuration with the following warning:

> Unexpected argument(s)
>
> Possible callees:
>
> basicConfig(*, filename:
>   Optional[str]=..., filemode: str=..., format: str=..., datefmt:
>   Optional[str]=..., level: Union[int, str, None]=..., stream:
>   IO[str]=...) basicConfig()
>
> Inspection info: Reports discrepancies
>   between declared parameters and actual arguments, as well as incorrect
>   arguments (e.g. duplicate named arguments) and incorrect argument
>   order. Decorators are analyzed, too.

And it goes out only if I remove the `handlers=[...]` part of the code.

Did the `basicConfig`'s arguments change on a specific version? If yes, what is the proposed way to achieve the same thing?

I'm using `python 3.6` and `pycharm 2020.1` (but had the same warning for at least the past 3 updates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is reported on PyCharm bug tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39762 . In short: the new keyword arguments of `basicConfig` in Python 3, like `handler`, are not recognized.

That issue also mentions a workaround:

> Put a caret on `basicConfig` - Right Click - Go to - Declaration or Usages - Click on a star on the left (on a gutter) - `logging/__init__.pyi` should be opened - Annotate **all** `basicConfig` definitions with `@overload`.

I tested it and it worked. In my case PyCharm no longer complains about `force=True` argument.

> Did the basicConfig's arguments change on a specific version?

You can always check the docs for that:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig :

> Changed in version 3.2: The style argument was added.
>
> Changed in version 3.3: The handlers argument was added. Additional checks were added to catch situations where incompatible arguments are specified (e.g. handlers together with stream or filename, or stream together with filename).
>
> Changed in version 3.8: The force argument was added.

Comment: this is the correct solution. works in IntellijIDEA as well.

Answer (score 2):

The bug still seems to be unresolved. The following solution just supresses the error.

```
# noinspection PyArgumentList
logging.basicConfig(...)
```